# Is there a definition of light/medium/heavy aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, icao

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked before but I couldn't find it by searching.

For separating arriving aircraft, [ICAO PANS-ATM-Doc 4444 Air Traffic Management](http://code7700.com/pdfs/icao_doc_4444_15th_edition.pdf) refers to aircraft as "LIGHT", "MEDIUM" or "HEAVY" but I cannot find any definition of what makes an aircraft fall into any particulate category.

I would of expected a limit on MTOW for each category, does such a definition exist or is it more of an informal definition?

> 5.8.2 · Arriving aircraft
>
> 5.8.2.1 Except as provided for in 5.8.l.l a) and b), the following separation minima shall be applied.
>
> 5.8.2.l.l The following minima shall be applied to aircraft landing behind a HEAVY or a MEDIUM aircraft:
>
> a) MEDIUM aircraft behind HEAVY aircraft- 2 minutes;
>
> b) LIGHT aircraft behind a HEAVY or MEDIUM aircraft- 3 minutes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Section 4.9.1.1 of [ICAO PANS-ATM-Doc 4444 Air Traffic Management](http://code7700.com/pdfs/icao_doc_4444_15th_edition.pdf) defines LIGHT, MEDIUM & HEAVY aircraft for the purpose of wake separation:

> #### 4.9.1 Wake turbulence categories of aircraft
>
> 4.9.1.1 Wake turbulence separation minima shall be based on a grouping of aircraft types into three categories according to the maximum certified take-off mass as follows:
>
> a) HEAVY (H) — all aircraft types of 136,000kg or more;
>
> b) MEDIUM (M) — all aircraft types less than 136,000kg but more than 7,000kg; and
>
> c) LIGHT (L) — aircraft types of 7,000kg or less.
>
> 4.9.1.2 Helicopters should be kept well clear of light aircraft when hovering or while air taxiing.
>
> *Note 1.— Helicopters produce vortices when in flight and there is some evidence that, per kilogram of gross mass, their vortices are more intense than those of fixed-wing aircraft.*
>
> *Note 2.— The provisions governing wake turbulence minima are set forth in Chapter 5, Section 5.8, and Chapter 8, Section 8.7.3.*

Answer (score 5):

Let me add the proposed **Super** category. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence#Wake_vortex_separation) and [this article](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/ICAO_Wake_Turbulence_Category):

> ICAO mandates separation minima based upon wake turbulence categories (WTC) that are, in turn, based upon the Maximum Take Off Mass (MTOW|MTOM) of the aircraft.
>
> These minima are typically categorised as follows:
>
> - Light (L)– MTOW of 7,000 kilograms (15,000 lb) or less;
> - Medium (M)– MTOW of greater than 7,000 kilograms, 
>      but less than 136,000 kilograms (300,000 lb);
> - Heavy (H)– MTOW of 136,000 kilograms (300,000 lb) or greater.
>
> **A fourth category is currently being taken into
>     consideration by ICAO:[¹](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/field_tabs/content/documents/nm/airports/airports-wake-vortex-aspects-letter-a380-aircraft1.pdf)**
>
> - **Super (J)– Refers only to the Airbus A380**
>
> Even though the resolution to add the "Super" category is still under consideration, both the FAA (see below) and EUROCONTROL have already implemented guidelines concerning the Airbus A380.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Doesn't "super" also include the An-225?

Comment: @StephenS [Apparenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence#Wake_turbulence_category) FAA says _yes_ but ICAO says _no_. Maybe it doesn't matter that much because the An-225 is such an exceptional and rare aircraft compared to the A380.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all anymore, unfortunately, @PerlDuck.

Comment: Oh yes, @randomhead, oh yes 

Answer (score 2):

The FAA answers this question here: [Weight Class](http://aspmhelp.faa.gov/index.php/Weight_Class)

> Weight Class
>   Weight class is based are assigned by APO130 based on the TFMS observed aircraft codes. There are 6 categories -- (A) Heavy, (B) B757, (C) Large Jet, (D) Large Commuter, (E) Medium, (F) Small.
>
> (A) Heavy: Any aircraft weighing more than 255,000 lb such as the Boeing 747 or the Airbus A340;
>
> (B) B757: Boeing 757 all series;
>
> (C) Large Jet: Large jet aircraft weighing more than 41,000 and up to 255,000 lbs such as the Boeing 737 or the Airbus A320;
>
> (D) Large Commuter: Large non-jet aircraft (such as the Aerospatiale/Alenia ATR-42 and the Saab SF 340), and small regional jets (such as the Bombardier Canadair Regional Jet), weighing more than 41,000 and up to 255,000 lbs;
>
> (E) Medium: Small commuter aircraft including business jets weighing more than 12,500 up to 41,000 lbs such as the Embraer 120 or the Learjet 35; and
>
> (F) Small: Small, single, or twin engine aircraft weighing 12,500 lbs or less such as the Beech 90 or the Cessna Caravan.
>
> Unknown; refers to unspecified equipment.

"Light" Aircraft follows the same definition as "Small" in the above text.

Wake turbulence is no joke - you can feel it if you come in behind a larger aircraft even several minutes after it lands, and often even if you stay above its glide path and land beyond its touchdown point, as you should.

There was a Grumman Tiger landing at my local airport that didn't pay attention, ignored the tower's "caution wake turbulence" warning, and got flipped inverted and subsequently crashed as a result of wake turbulence from a UH-60 military helicopter that had departed several minutes prior. The pilot, very fortunately, walked away but the aircraft was ruined.

Note that even though helicopters are not mentioned in your post - any helicopter leaves persistent rotor wash and you should be extremely cautious and wait several minutes before attempting to takeoff or land anywhere a helicopter has been.

Comment: This question is about ICAO L/M/H categories, not about FAA classifications

Comment: @60levelchange Pugz was describing the Wake Recat categories; the FAA also [defines](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-a.html#%24AIRCRAFT%20CLASSES) "heavy/large/small" in a similar way to ICAO's "heavy/medium/light," although the dividing lines are placed at different weights than ICAO's lines.

Answer (score -3):

please note that there is a "Super" category only for A380 as the wake turbulence can cause issues even for Heavy aircraft if they use the same seperations as "Heavy-Heavy"

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! If you use the answer field, it is expected here that you provide a full answer to the question. This currently reads more like a comment to the other answers. Could you expand this a bit to turn it into a complete answer?